# UIStatus Bar Color issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, ios7

For showing status bar in iOS 7 did the following code :-

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
 {
   if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0"))
    {
     CGRect viewBounds = self.view.bounds;
     CGFloat topBarOffset = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
     viewBounds.origin.y = topBarOffset * -1;
     self.view.bounds = viewBounds;
    }
  }
```

[image: iOS Simulator 4 inch screen]

[image: iOS Simulator 3.5 inch screen]

As you can see in the image status bar color changes for both iOS Simulator 3.5 inch (iPhone 4/4s) and 4 inch (iPhone 5) .I want to show my status bar color white in 3.5 inch screens also. So, Please help me out from this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: draw a view with white color in each and every view at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your `PLIST`, and add this flag:

```
View controller-based status bar appearance = NO
```

next, in your AppDelegate in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` add this:

```
[[ UIApplication sharedApplication ] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent animated:YES ];
```

after checking if your device is ios7. `UIStatusBarStyleLightContent` is new.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :- I dont want to change text color, background color to white and text color to black as you can see in iOS simulator 4 inch screen screenshot.